# Spacing Nav Menu

Tags: html

I have a problem resizing or spacing a navigation menu as seen on the pic below. If any body knows how, please inform me. I just wanna resize nav menu box so the first one become like the second one (to resize it smaller).

[image]

HTML

```
<!--MENU-->
    <nav id = "main-nav-menu">
      <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        <li><a href="about-us.html">ABOUT US</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="products.html">OUR PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="equipments.html">OUR EQUIPMENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="machine_list.html">MACHINE LIST</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end menu -->
```

CSS

```
#header .menu select {
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
display: block;
left: 4px;
position: relative;
top: 205px;
width: 250px;
}


#header .menu select {
display: block;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some of the menu's code, otherwise it is impossible to answer. The resizing will likely involve some CSS changing, but we can't be sure if we have no code at all.

Comment: This is some of menu's code

#header .menu select {
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
display: block;
left: 4px;
position: relative;
top: 205px;
width: 250px;
}

#header .menu select {
display: block;
width: 200px;
}

Comment: Thats better. Can you provide the HTML code as well? (That's CSS.) Also, it is better if you edit your question and add the codes to it (rather than pasting them as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with some simple css rules. in your stylesheet, or style block if you're not using a style sheet, you need to set max or min widths, as well as padding for your list items. 
add something like:

```
li{max-width:60px;padding:4px;}
```

or

```
.sf-menu li{max-width:60px;padding:4px;}
```

or

```
main-nav-menu ul li{max-width:60px;padding:4px;}
```

each of these will set the maximum width of your menu items to 60px. Change this value to suit your needs. This means there will be a standard width for all items. You could also set a fixed width or min-width.

```
li{min-width:60px;width:100px;max-width:150px;}
```

you can also add padding to keep a consistant look.

```
li{padding:4px 8px;} /* top & bottom padding of 4px, left & right padding of 8px */
```

an example of this code - http://jsfiddle.net/kcdP4/

hope this helps

Comment: First i wanna say thanks, It's work...but the menu text be dropped down. 

.sf-menu li{max-width:140px;padding:0px;}
http://mjtoolsindo.com/stack/1.jpg

.sf-menu li{max-width:100px;padding:0px;}
http://mjtoolsindo.com/stack/2.jpg

Awaiting your reply, Regards.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then setting the vertical alignment of the list items to top, should do this for you. You also need to set center alignment of the text. Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kcdP4/2/  I have added a line break to the 'about us' link. This can be removed if you prefer it to be on one line.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, really appreciate it, but just to clarify further, what I wanted to achieve, is to reduce the button space beside the titles, like the picture attached earlier, but without causing title which have to words to go down, which means everthing stays on one line. So in short, The "button" smaller, the text stays the same size, same alignment. Previous solution, educes the button size, but forces title which have 2 words like "Our Products" to become 2 lines. 

If you guys can help me on this, I will be really grateful.

Comment: you can adjust the min and max width values. change max-width to 140px, min width to whatever you want. Or set the width to a specific value. The spacing within the buttons is changed with the padding value. The spacing between buttons is the margin. Here's the update http://jsfiddle.net/kcdP4/4/